# Domain controller not appearing in DNS on any server but itself?

Tags: windows-server-2008, domain-name-system, active-directory, domain-controller

I have a site with a DC I want to decommission, and a relatively new one (promo'd within the last two weeks).  I'm having trouble demoting the old server, and in the process of trying to figure out why I'm running `repadmin /replsum` on a few of my DCs.

On most of them, I'm getting the error:

> Experienced the following operational errors trying to retrieve replication information:
>
> `58 - c7908eb4-5ef4-46a7-b445-642b33ece726._msdcs.domain.com`

I've looked around in DNS on the rest of my DCs looking for this listing, and I finally found it on my new DC mentioned above, and it refers to itself!  So every other DC appears not to know about this DC, at least from a DNS perspective, but running `repadmin /replsum` on my new DC does not return any errors.

Why would this be happening, and what's the best way to correct it?

Comment: Can you describe what DNS Server each DC is using (ipconfig /all on each server?) or at least one old and the new one?

Comment: Oh, hm, yes, that's probably an issue... the new server is using the to-be-decommissioned DC and a DC in our main site.  The to-be-decomissioned DC is using two DCs from our main site.

Comment: As long as it doesn't point to itself (and the to-be decommissioned server works as it should) I doubt that's the source of the error.

Comment: Everything is prod here... I'm hesitant to demote it.

Comment: I would also encourate you to read thru this post regarding multiple copies of the DNS zone. There might be some quick ways to fix your issue:
http://blogs.technet.com/b/askpfeplat/archive/2012/02/05/am-i-seeing-double-the-case-of-quot-multiple-copies-of-the-same-dns-zone-quot.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually they all just figured it out, I guess.  I took a look a few days later and the relevant DNS entries existed and I'm no longer getting any errors running `repadmin`.